# file transfer as a web service in j2se

Tags: java, web-services

hi i am a newbie in developing web service. as a part of my module i need to develop a web service to transfer files from server to client using java(j2se). can you help me out with providing the source code?

Comment: What do you need it for? HTTP, FTP, XML-RPC, SOAP or something else? What kind of services does the server provide?

Comment: That question is generic and too vague

Comment: It's worth remembering that StakOverflow isn't a place to get people to do your work for you. It's a Q&A site, so do some research, like looking at the links Tomas Narros gave you in his answer, give it a try. Should you come up with any **specific** problems, you can post your code to date and I'm sure someone will be happy to help at that point.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need some guidelines before starting your WS design and implementation. I really think that just posting you a sample code for copy-pasting without understanding what are you doing won't really help you.

You could start checking the [reference tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/) from Oracle site, specially, the chapter on the [SOAP With Attachments API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/SAAJ.html#wp69380).  There you have also some code examples, and a good explanation on what to do and why.